# Makefile command line argument is not resolving

Tags: command-line, makefile

My makefile looks like this:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -g3
LIBS = `pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0`
BINDIR = bin
OUTOBJ = $(addprefix $(BINDIR)/, main.o) 
$(info INCLUDE_PATH:$(INCLUDE_PATH))

$(BINDIR)/%.o : %.c 
                $(CC) -c $< $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $(LIBS)

# TODO: Merge with above rule
$(BINDIR)/%.o : */%.c 
                $(CC) -c $(INCLUDE_PATH) $< $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $(LIBS)


all: $(OUTOBJ)

$(OUTOBJ): | $(BINDIR)

$(BINDIR):
            mkdir $(BINDIR)

.PHONY : clean
clean:
        rm bin/*
```

When I invoke make like this:

```
make INCLUDE_PATH="/my/proj/dir"
```

I get output like this:

```
INCLUDE_PATH:/my/proj/dir
gcc -c main.c -g3 -o bin/main.o `pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0`

.....
.....
```

So looking at the output, the $(info INCLUDE_PATH:$(INCLUDE_PATH)) statement at the beginning of the file basically resolves fine, but inside the task $(INCLUDE_PATH) variable does not resolve. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Can you please try `$(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDE_PATH) $< -o $@ $(LIBS)` and/or `$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $(INCLUDE_PATH) $< -o $@ $(LIBS)`?

Comment: Why do you think the second of the two rules to generate `$(BINDIR)/%.o` is being used?

Comment: @G.M. Thanks for pointing out. This is now fixed with the use of VPATH. I no longer have a need to use two different capture rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So looking at the output, the $(info INCLUDE_PATH:$(INCLUDE_PATH)) statement at the beginning of the file basically resolves fine, but inside the task $(INCLUDE_PATH) variable does not resolve.

No, that's not it at all.  As @G.M. observed in comments, you have two different pattern rules for building object files in `$(BINDIR)`, and they differ with respect to whether their recipes reference `$(INCLUDE_PATH)`.  The output you present is consistent with the first being applied instead of the second.  And **that is exactly what I would expect**, because the prerequisite pattern in the second rule, `*/%.c`, *does not match* the prerequisite actually being being used, `main.c`, whose name does not contain a `/` character.

For your example makefile, you could replace both `$(BINDIR)/%.o` rules with this rule ...

```
$(BINDIR)/%.o : %.c 
        $(CC) -c -I$(INCLUDE_PATH) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $< $(LIBS)
```

... to resolve the issue, but really this is poor form for a couple of reasons.  First and foremost, at least a default value of `INCLUDE_PATH` should be given in the makefile itself, especially if it refers to another part of the same project.  Secondarily, it would be more idiomatic to collect `-I` (and `-D`, `-U`, and maybe some other) directives into a variable named `CPPFLAGS`, and use *that* in your build rules:

```
CPPFLAGS = -I$(INCLUDE_PATH)

$(BINDIR)/%.o : %.c 
        $(CC) -c $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $< $(LIBS)
```

The resulting rule is closely analogous to `make`'s built-in rule for building an object file from a single corresponding source file.

In general, I'm not a big fan of building objects in a different directory than their corresponding sources, as it goes against the grain, and therefore takes more work to set up and is much more fiddly.  Whether your real project is large or small, I really don't see how the effort is justified.  If you want out-of-source builds then go all the way and use [VPATH](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Directory-Search.html#index-vpath).

Comment: That was it! Now looking back this was rather a stupid question. But thanks for all the interesting points you bring up. I will look at VPATH; But I definitely want to dump all .o files in bin/

Comment: I was also able to incorporate VPATH and get rid of multiple rules for capturing %.c in multiple subdirs. Very helpful indeed!